# Why does GCC not check constraints for template specializations in namespaces

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code fails to compile on GCC, but works on MSVC and Clang ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WGfe76so8)):

```cpp
#include <concepts>

namespace s {
template<typename T>
struct my_struct {
    
};
}

template<std::integral T>
struct s::my_struct<T> {};

template<std::floating_point V>
struct s::my_struct<V> {};

int main() {
    s::my_struct<int> s{};
    s::my_struct<float> s2{};
}
```

The compile error refers to the second specialization (`s::my_struct<V>`) as being a redefinition of `s::my_struct<T>`. As far as I understand this shouldn't be happening as the constraints on them are mutually exclusive, also it works outside the namespace ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8szhrnx1c)). Is this an ambiguity in the standard, or a bug with GCC?

Comment: You use C++20 which is standardized, but not fully supported by compilers yet. Some compilers already have some C++20 features other not and there are some new bugs.

Comment: @MarekR So its a gcc bug then?

Comment: First check implemented features, but IMO yes this is bug (maybe some langue layer could explain in details why).

Comment: `s::my_struct<V>` is a template partial specialization of `s::my_struct<T>`. Thus, gcc is wrong here since it is not a redefinition.

Comment: It thinks it is a redefinition of the other partial specialization, because it is ignoring the constraints. There's a bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92944